# Basic DLNA Server; like - cough - on W10

Tags: kubuntu, client, tv, dlna

What I am trying to achieve: **similar to W10**, where I can right-click on a file, and thereby send a video to the DLNA client. Nothing else.

By now, I have spent some days, and installed some software, from **Rygel** to **HMS**. HMS would be a complete overkill, and comparatively difficult to use. Rygel kind of produces a server.

My client isn't smart, has limits of files that can be processed, and I have some 10.000 files. No way.

My dream would be a file manager in **Kubuntu**, or an extension to a file manager, that simply allows me to send the file that I want to view instead of on VLC to my TV. Out and over.

For the time being nothing actually works, except I boot to W10. The client is a SONY Bravia.

I still hope that someone out there can help me to not dual-boot, but simply somehow send a file that I select on kubuntu to the TV. I did read that ubuntu offers some 'Sharing' option, but it isn't available in the kubuntu settings.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your post you are looking for 2 things.
A lightweight server : MiniDLNA (I use this and it is discovered by clients on multiple devices)
A client - to direct file to a renderer. A quick google shows RhythmBox with Grillo plugins can do this.
For Video VLC will direct video to specified renderer.

Comment: The trick I was looking for was the VLC-thing. Alas, it doesn't work.
On the Sony TV under 'Home Network Setup' it shows under 'Server Display Settings', It 'succeeded' in Server Diagnostic. 
Under Render Access Control it doesn't show, however. That is where the W10 machine shows. I deleted that one, then Render Access Control becomes empty. Though with the subsequent start on W10, it pops up once again. Only I can't get MiniDLNA to send anything(?), or pop up under Render Access Control one or another way.
So the Renderer in VLC remains grey, with 'Scanning ...'.
What next?

Comment: MiniDLNA doesn't 'send' as such - it is discoverable on UPNP and is a provider. If it is working it should just show up on a UPNP client (BubbleUPNP app on a phone can be used to test/check). No real fix if Sony TV not seen as a renderer. FYI BubbleUPNP will connect any provider to any renderer and may help...

Comment: Thanks very much for the recommendation! The outcome was the expected: Since the SONY works properly as renderer for W10, it also worked immediately and properly with bubbleUPNP.. Meaning, it is not the linux-stack that is in the way. 
To my humble opinion it rather points to a VLC-Problem. I am sitting on 3.0.16 Vetenari, standard on kubuntu 22.04. What could I do; report a bug?